# Add custom query parameter to action URL in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, url-routing, query-string

In ASP.NET Core MVC, I'd like to make it so that URLs created with `Url.Action` and action-based tag helpers include a custom query parameter in the URL. I want to apply this globally, regardless of the controller or action.

I tried [overriding the default route handler](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39996443/3), which worked at one time, but  broke with an ASP.NET Core update. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding it to the collection instead of overriding the `DefaultHandler`. The following worked for me on version 1.1.2:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    // ... other configuration
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.Routes.Add(new HostPropagationRouter(routes.DefaultHandler));
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
    // ... other configuration
}
```

Here's the router, just for completeness.

```
public class HostPropagationRouter : IRouter
{
    readonly IRouter router;

    public HostPropagationRouter(IRouter router)
    {
        this.router = router;
    }

    public VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(VirtualPathContext context)
    {
        if (context.HttpContext.Request.Query.TryGetValue("host", out var host))
            context.Values["host"] = host;
        return router.GetVirtualPath(context);
    }

    public Task RouteAsync(RouteContext context) => router.RouteAsync(context);
}
```

Comment: That worked, but I wish I better understood why. Can you explain or point to documentation on how `IRouteBuilder.Routes` and `IRouteBuilder.DefaultHandler` interact with each other and with routes created through `MapRoute`?

Comment: @EdwardBrey I don't know enough to answer your question definitively. However, I do know that the change in behavior is [related to this bug fix](https://github.com/aspnet/Routing/issues/370). The values being passed were not properly being passed down the line.